# jQuery Flot multiline Chart Drawing over itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I am attempting to draw to lines onto a line chart using flot. I am getting half way there, the two lines draw on the chart, but they are scrabbled into one another. I've attempted to copy another working one, but swapping out the values and getting a similar result.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Graphs = function () {

return {

    //main function

    initCharts: function () {
        if (!jQuery.plot) {
            return;
        }

        function showChartTooltip(x, y, xValue, yValue) {
            $('<div id="tooltip" class="chart-tooltip">' + yValue + '<\/div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y - 40,
                left: x - 40,
                border: '0px solid #ccc',
                padding: '2px 6px',
                'background-color': '#fff'
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }

        var data = [];

        // random data generator for plot charts

        if ($('#site_revenue').size() != 0) {
            //site revenue
            var previousPoint2 = null;
            $('#site_revenue_loading').hide();
            $('#site_revenue_content').show();

    var data1 = [
    ['Sep', 1061.93],
['Oct', 2865.28],
['Nov', 0.00], 
['Dec', 4129.21], 
['Jan', 6021.44],
['Mar', 2289.62],
['Mar', 2289.62],
['Apr', 1561.96],
['May', 1839.25],
['Jun', 937.00],
['Jul', 921.35],
['Aug', 6653.98],
                ];

            var data2 = [
['Sep', 0.00],
['Aug', 6653.98],
['Jul', 921.35],
['Jun', 937.00],
['May', 1839.25],
['Apr', 1561.96],
['Mar', 2289.62],
['Feb', 2661.91],
['Jan', 6021.44],
['Dec', 4129.21],
['Nov', 0.00],
['Oct', 2865.28],
                ];

            var plot_statistics = $.plot($("#site_revenue"),

                [{
                    data: data1,
                    color: ['#BAD9F5'],
                    label: "Revenue", 
                    points: {
                        fillColor: "#9ACAE6",
                    },
                    shadowSize: 1
                }, {
                    data: data2,
                    color: ['#d12610'],
                    label: "Revenue Rev",
                    points: {
                        fillColor: "#d12610",
                    },
                     shadowSize: 1
                }]


                );

            var previousPoint2 = null;
            $("#site_revenue").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
                $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
                if (item) {
                    if (previousPoint2 != item.dataIndex) {
                        previousPoint2 = item.dataIndex;
                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.datapoint[0], '$' + item.datapoint[1]);
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });

            $('#site_revenue').bind("mouseleave", function () {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
            });
        }
    }

};

}();
</script>
```

Comment: Your data arrays are ordered differently. That could be the problem. If it is not please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your problem.

Comment: Yes, Can you please give a fiddle or at least a picture ilustrating problem? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I assume you are using the categories plugin?  You'll need:

```
  {
    xaxis: {
      mode: 'categories'
    }
  }
```

in the options object.

Second, as @Raidri hints at flot is just plotting your data in the order you gave it (hence lines "going backward").  It's up to you to sort and QC your data.  I think what you meant was:

```
// this was properly sorted
var data1 = [
  ['Sep', 1061.93],
  ['Oct', 2865.28],
  ['Nov', 0.00], 
  ['Dec', 4129.21], 
  ['Jan', 6021.44],
  ['Feb', 2289.62], // this was a duplicate 'Mar', did you mean 'Feb'?
  ['Mar', 2289.62],
  ['Apr', 1561.96],
  ['May', 1839.25],
  ['Jun', 937.00],
  ['Jul', 921.35],
  ['Aug', 6653.98]
];

// I sorted this
var data2 = [
  ['Sep', 0.00],
  ['Oct', 2865.28],
  ['Nov', 0.00],
  ['Dec', 4129.21],
  ['Jan', 6021.44],
  ['Feb', 2661.91],
  ['Mar', 2289.62],
  ['Apr', 1561.96],
  ['May', 1839.25],
  ['Jun', 937.00],
  ['Jul', 921.35],
  ['Aug', 6653.98]
];
```

Finally, when using the categories plugin, I would make sure that all categories are represented in each series.  If you are missing values at certain categories in a specific series I'd insert `nulls`.

Here's a fixed [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wr04hTKKPcQLPRrNGkhR?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, it was the data, sorting. Can't believe I was stupid enough to get the categories wrong. Clearly was working on this way too long.